# Visual Studio 2012 Intellisense - group items instead of alphabetically ordering them

Tags: visual-studio-2012, intellisense

Does anybody know if it is possible to change the order that the items appear in Intellisense so that they are grouped together into properties, subs, functions etc. rather than the default alphabetical order.

E.g.

```
Class MyClass
    Public Property BiscuitProperty
    Public Property ElephantProperty
    Public Sub DogSub
    Public Sub AnacondaSub
    Public Function ChocolateFunction
End Class
```

After typing "myClass." these would by default appear as follows:

1. AnacondaSub
2. BiscuitProperty
3. ChocolateFunction
4. DogSub
5. ElephantProperty

Ideally I would like them to appear in the following order:

1. BiscuitProperty
2. ElephantProperty
3. AnacondaSub
4. DogSub
5. ChocolateFunction

I've had a look through the options and had a read on-line and can't find anything so I am guessing it probably isn't possible but thought it was worth an ask.

Thanks,

Al

Comment: Thanks Hans, I thought it might be so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Options for IntelliSense in the Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> IntelliSense settings, this is not possible...

Comment: Interestingly, there's no Intellisense option under the VB section of the text editor settings so I didn't spot those. Thanks.